# is it possible to parse and consume the results of an aeson parser from a stream in constant space?

Tags: parsing, haskell, streaming, aeson

Note that **[fromJson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:fromJSON)** returns a **Result a**, which can be an **Error String** or **Success a**.

If I'm using fromJson on a stream  (for example, a [response](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-streams-0.7.2.5/docs/Network-Http-Client.html#g:4) from http-streams using the expression `parseFromStream (fromJSON <$> json')` ) [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams-1.2.1.2/docs/System-IO-Streams-Attoparsec.html), does pattern matching on the Result force the whole stream to buffer completely first, in order to the parse to determine success or failure, regardless of whether further consumption of the response is sufficiently lazy (i.e. constant-space parsing+consumption *is not* possible) ?  Or, can the **both** parsing and result be consumed lazily i.e. constant-space parsing+consumption *is* possible)?  The docs sau "parseFromStream consumes only as much input as necessary to satisfy the Parser", but it's not clear how "satisfing the Parser" relates to pattern matching on the Result to Produce a Success or Error.

(P.S. Alternatively, it is not possible, is there a different way that allows constant-space parsing w/ consumption?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in general. The approach I took when writing [xml-conduit](http://www.stackage.org/package/xml-conduit) was to have the parser parse out individual *events*, like "element begin" and "element end." I've considered many times in the past having a similar Haskell library for JSON data.

There actually is something like this available as a C library binding: [yajl](http://www.stackage.org/package/yajl).

Comment: It seems json is bad for parsing incrementally since fields can arrive in any order.  yajl does parse incrementally, but it might not be so useful if you want to parse into a user data structure because the result is not usable until the whole stream has been consumed: SAX "parsers" are more or less just lexers, giving you a sequence of tokens, not for deserialising xml to structures  (unless you are able to restrict yourself to only parsing a "json list" at the top level).  You would have to you instead have to "accumulate" your result, updating it whenever a field that you care about arrives

Answer (score 1):

I have just roughly completed a json parser that does incremental parsing. Both result and input can be consumed lazily, it is constant space as far as constant space is possible. See if this helps you:
https://github.com/ondrap/json-stream